# Update Pivot Table Week Number in VBA Using a Constant Value

Tags: vba, excel

We are trying to get our Excel to update the value of the Pivot Table based on a user input in two cells. It should update the part in the code where it says 2016014 and 2017014. (014 is the week number). We instruct the user to enter the week number using YYYYWWW format in cells AD and AE (one for 2016 and one for 2017). How do we get Excel to read the value from those inputs?

Would we declare something like this? Only problem is I get an

> Invalid attribute in Sub or Function

```
        Public Const weekNumber1 As String = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Charts).Cells(30, 4).Value
        Public Const weekNumber2 As String = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Charts).Cells(31, 4).Value
```

Here is the actual code:

```
Sub WeekUpdate(Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
                        If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Qtr]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week].&[2016014]")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Qtr]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week].&[2017014]")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
```

Here is the second part of the code (it calls the first part):

```
End Sub

Sub DoSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Charts" Then
        WeekUpdate ws
        ws.Cells(1, 1) = 1
    End If
Next

starting_ws.Activate

End Sub
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
Public Function weekNumber1() As String
    weekNumber1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Cells(4, 30).Value
End Function
Public Function weekNumber2() As String
    weekNumber2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Cells(5, 30).Value
End Function


Sub WeekUpdate(Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
            If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Qtr]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week].&[weekNumber1()]")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Qtr]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week].&[weekNumber2()]")
            ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
End Sub


Sub DoSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Charts" Then
        WeekUpdate ws
        ws.Cells(1, 1) = 1
    End If
Next

starting_ws.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: For starters a Public Const can't be set as a variable. It is a constant. Also, it looks like it would be local scope anyway. Also, why 014? Does the week numbers run across years i.e. go beyond 52/3? For the rest, you would probably be looking at concatenating in the variable to the string which was  [2017014]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's impossible to declare a constant with a variable value, one solution is to have a public function -- with no parameters -- which supplies the desired value, such as:

```
Public Function weekNumber1() As String
    weekNumber1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Cells(30, 4).Value
End Function

Public Function weekNumber2() As String
    weekNumber2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Cells(31, 4).Value
End Function
```

You would call/use it in code, the same way you'd use the constants.

---

Since you are using the value in a string, you should change this:

```
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week].&[weekNumber2()]")
```

to this:

```
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week].&[" & weekNumber2() & "]")
```

You should also update the string referencing weekNumber1()

*Explanation of Edit*

You need to supply the sting in the format it's looking for. However, to call the Function (or use a variable' value) in the string, you need to append the pieces of the string together. If you included the Function (or variable) name as part of the string, VBA will use the literal text you have included instead of substituting the proper value.

**Edited**

Changed `Charts` to `"Charts"` since `Charts` is the worksheet *Name*

Comment: That is a part answer to the OPs problem I would say as they still need to concatenate that value in. I am also wondering if they have set Charts up so it can be called as Worksheet(Charts) as well given elsewhere they test for if name is "Charts". They may have...just wondering.

Comment: @QHarr I'm slightly confused about your comment on `Charts`. Are you referencing the `.CodeName` property?

Comment: I appreciate your help! I think I am getting closer. Now it's giving me an error that the item could not be found in the OLAP cube, meaning it's not using the value of the cell correctly. Any ideas? The cells I am trying to read are $AD$4 and $AD$5.

Comment: I don't know if Charts is a variable or a mistake I guess is what I am saying. It it was a code name I am not sure they would use the Worksheet part. But musing and please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Charts is the name of the sheet that has the cell values I am trying to read in.

Comment: I wonder if if the type should be String or something else? Is there a "type" for Pivot Table values?

Comment: @bored_gamer Since `Charts` is the name of the sheet, I'm surprised the Functions hadn't been throwing errors. `.Sheets()` is supposed to either have an index (numeral) or name(string). Since the name is being used, you should make sure it's being input to `.Sheets` as a string value. See the edit to my post....

Comment: @bored_gamer Also, could you **add** to your question your edited code? For me, I would at least like to see how you're attempting to use the functions. I would also appreciate it if you left our old code up there, for comparison.

Comment: Thank you! But it's still giving me the error that it could not find it in the OLAP cube. Any ideas? Maybe weekNumber1() should be declared as a different type?

Comment: @bored_gamer I edited my answer with an explanation of what should fix your issue. I ran into a similar problem myself, when I was starting to explore updating pivot tables and such with VBA.  :)

Comment: @bored_gamer You're welcome. I'm glad we were able to figure it out.  :)